# How to force a Terminal Command to run with the Performance Cores on Apple Silicon?

Tags: terminal, performance, apple-silicon

I recently had to reinstall the developer tools using `xcode-select —install`, but noticed that the install was completed with my efficiency cores rather than my performance cores. I know this because iStatMenu showed me that my four efficiency cores were at 100% most of the time while the performance cores were inactive.

Is there a way I can manually set the priority of a process? Can I tell a process to run on the performance cores if needed? Ideally, it would actually use as many cores as it had threads, and run on all 8 cores simultaneously.

An answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/419758/how-to-execute-terminal-command-on-energy-efficient-cores-on-m1-chip) describes how to run a task with the efficiency cores, which is equally useful, but I couldn't figure out how to adapt that technique to use the performance cores instead.

Comment: How are you determining your task is even CPU bound? What specific command do you run to reinstall your tools? An edit might help us be precise in steps to accelerate and use the hardware.

Comment: I used ```xcode-select —install``` which opens a window promting if I want developer tools. I suspect it is CPU bound because my iStatMenu CPU monitor shows 100% efficiency core utilization after it finished downloading. I know the performance cores are ~5x faster so I would like to be able to force the program to use those.

Comment: Superb details! I’ll try to benchmark this a bit. Curious what we can learn. I know Xcode itself is just starting to have flags to parallelize builds - so the command line tools might lag a release…

Comment: @JacobWaters Can you explain a bit more about the use case here? - Installing the developer tools like that is something you do once - it's normally not part of a developer's daily work.

Comment: Well every time I update MacOS it uninstalls the developer tools. Today I had to submit something under extreme time pressure, and I failed to meet an assignment deadline because xcode took too long. There are other processes which run slowly in the background on the performance cores, such as TimeMachine, and I have wanted to force the process to speed up in the past.

Answer (score 4):

You should note that the linked to answer works by "clamping" the QoS setting for the program - i.e. effectively putting a limit on how "well" thr program should be treated by the system.

This question is actually the opposite that we want to put a limit on how "bad" the program could be treated by the system.

I.e. even if `xcode-select --install` actually asks for the performance cores, it could under normal circumstances still be forced to run on efficiency cores if the performance cores are used for other things.

I would recommend starting by using `taskinfo` to gain information about the specific program. I.e. start up the installation process and run the following command in the Terminal:

```
sudo taskinfo 1234
```

where `1234` is the PID of the `xcode-select` process, you have started.

This will let you know a lot of useful information about the process, in particular you can see which scheduling policy is being used, the QoS clamp, and the latency and thruput QoS settings. Note that these values are shown first as the "requested policy" and then again as the "effective policy".

Depending on your system setup, I would assume that you find the reason for running on efficiency cores in the output. Then use the `taskpolicy` command to set a new through tier with the `-t` option or a new latency tier with the `l` option. You can also use the `nice` command to alter the scheduling priority.

Comment: Would you consider posting some example commands which would modify the priority of the process?

Comment: After a bit of trial and errors, it seems to me that the inputs of `taskpolicy -l` and `-t` are integers from 0 to 5 included

Comment: Yes, that's right - you give an integer from 0-5 and that's interpreted as LATENCY_QOS_TIER_x (where x is 0-5) or THROUGHPUT_QOS_TIER_x (where x is 0-5). The default is tier 3 for both.

Answer (score 4):

When process is already running I execute:

```
taskpolicy -B -p <pid>
```

It it's another user process:

```
sudo taskpolicy -B -p <pid>
```

When starting a new process you can use:

```
taskpolicy -c utility <your command>
```

Comment: it would be helpful to explain this answer more for those that are unfamiliar with priorities, scheduling policies, PRIO_DARWIN_BG, etc.